# Declaring an unknown number of DropDownLists as having certain styles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, styling

To lay some background, I have a section of an intranet site where users add skills to a profile, but with the nature of skills, there are new ones always added, so I can never know exactly how many skills I will have.

I have a custom styling that I apply to my `Html.DropDownLists` :

```
<script>

    $(function () {
        $(".response").combobox();
    }); 

</script>
```

This normally works fine, but due to the nature of the data I'm trying to capture, I have to name my DropDownLists with an incremental array. It works something like this when drawing up the HTML:

```
//Declare int answerIndex as 0

//foreach answer in questions ViewBag

@Html.DropDownList("answers[" + answerIndex + "].Response", new SelectList(ViewBag.Responses, "Id", "Name"), "")

//answerIndex++;

//end foreach
```

My UpdateSkills method on my controller class takes in the variable:

```
SQEPAnswer[] answers
```

Which deems the above necessary - it takes in all the details of the answer.

However, the simple styling option referenced at first - I can't figure out a way to apply it reliably, I guess I could declare an array of style options in my js but that makes my spine crawl...

If anyone knows how I can apply my styling to my DropDownLists, I would be very appreciative - I'm a competent enough programmer but this area of programming is not my strongest point.

I am using Razor markup on MVC #4, any questions/comments are welcome to help me get to where I want.

Comment: I don't understand: do you apply class "response" to each drop down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured this one out after leaving it for a while, sorry for the ambiguity in the question -

```
@Html.DropDownList("answers[" + answerIndex + "].Response", new SelectList(ViewBag.Responses, "Id", "Name"), "", new { @class = "response" })
```

This applied the styling to all DropDownLists, regardless of how many were generated.